# Graph database with Erlang driver

Tags: database-recommendation, graph

I need a graph database system that has an Erlang driver.

Can you advise which database system to use?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any better hope of answering this, but you can use Neo4J from Erlang...  see https://github.com/nerlo/nerlo/wiki/howto-use-neo4j-from-erlang